# 'this' reference in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, this

I have a little problem in object programming in javascript

There is a "class" Task, it has several methods, a method containing an asynchronous sending of a request with a help of JQuery (`$.ajax`). After request is success it's necessary to perform a particular method (e.g. successFunction) of the class Task.

The problem is, after the query in the body of successFunction it's impossible to refer to the class using the keyword `this`, because the context has changed, and this contains a reference to the **jquery-object** which performs an **ajax-request**.

What variants to refer to the current Task object inside a function that was not caused directly but externally exist? (For example by an event or ajax)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Normally inside an AJAX event such as the success callback, `this` refers to the object returned by the `$.ajax` call. You could use the `context` parameter to change the context in the success callback:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/foo',
    context: this, // <!-- change the context of the success callback
    success: function(result) {
        // 'this' here will refer to whatever it refered outside
    } 
});
```

You could also pass complex objects:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/foo',
    context: { element: this, foo: 'bar' },
    success: function(result) {
        // you can use 'this.element' and 'this.foo' here
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 9):

You can define a variable which holds the reference to the object:

```
function Task() {
  var that = this;
  this.call = function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: '/foo',
      success: function(result) {
        console.log(that); // <-- you cann access this object via that
      }
    });
  };
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**`this` in JavaScript**

Every time the execution phase(code starts executing) is created in javascript. JS engine provides `this` keyword to us.

**1. Logging in JS file (say script.js)**

```
console.log(this);
```

this points to the global object (window).

> Window {postMessage: ƒ, blur: ƒ, focus: ƒ, close: ƒ, frames:
>   Window, …}

---

**2. Inside a function**

```
function a(){
   console.log(this);
}
a();
```

When used in a function, this refers to the **Global object (window)**.

> Window {postMessage: ƒ, blur: ƒ, focus: ƒ, close: ƒ, frames:
>   Window, …}

---

**3. "use strict"**

```
"use strict";
function myFunction() {
    console.log(this);
}
```

In strict mode, this will be undefined, because strict mode does not allow default binding.

> undefined

---

**4. function expression**

```
var b = function(){
 console.log(this);
}
b();
```

When used in a function expression, this refers to the **Global object (window)**.

> Window {postMessage: ƒ, blur: ƒ, focus: ƒ, close: ƒ, frames:
>   Window, …}

---

**5. Object method**

```
var c = {
   name : "John",
   log : function(){
     console.log(this);
  }
}
c.log();
```

`this` refers to `c` object.

> {name: "John", log: ƒ}

**6. Function inside object method**

```
var d = {
   name : "John",
   log : function(){
     console.log(this);
     // refers to d object

    var setname = function(){
        console.log(this);
       //refer to global object (window)
    }
    setname();
  }
}
d.log();
```

This is quirk mode of javascript. Use below code to fix.

```
var d = {
   name : "John",
   log : function(){
      var self = this;
      // in some js library `that` is used

     console.log(self);
     // refers to d object

    var setname = function(){
        console.log(self);
        console.log(self.name);
       //refers to d object
    }
    setname();
  }
}
d.log();
```

`this` refers to `d` object.

> {name: "John", log: ƒ}

Answer (score 0):

Use closures. You can read about them here:

http://www.using-jquery.com/2010/12/what-are-javascript-closures/